# room.schemaLocation for each flavors

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-room, android-productflavors, kapt

I've a multi flavors project which represents several brands, each with their own database and I'm figuring out a simple way to export a room schema for each of them.

e.g:

flavor#1 -> "$projectDir/flavor1/schemas"
flavor#2 -> "$projectDir/flavor2/schemas"

I tried to add this

```
    kapt {
        arguments {
            arg("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/myFlavorName/schemas")
        }
    }
```

inside a each flavor { } block but doesn't work (it works for "last" flavor only)
Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

With [room plugin (2.6.+)](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions#set_schema_location_using_room_gradle_plugin) you can achieve that by defining a custom schema location inside your flavor declaration in app build.gradle.kts file :

```
productFlavors {
    create("yourFlavorName1") {
        ...
        room {
            schemaDirectory(
                variantMatchName = "yourFlavorName1",
                path = "$projectDir/schemas/customDir1"
            )
        }
        ...
    }
    create("yourFlavorName2") {
        ...
        room {
            schemaDirectory(
                variantMatchName = "yourFlavorName2",
                path = "$projectDir/schemas/customDir2"
            )
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

As stated [here](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/room/room-gradle-plugin/2.6.0-rc01-source/androidx/room/gradle/RoomGradlePlugin.kt.html) inside
`private fun configureVariant(...)`, variantMatchName is compared against several type of name, flavorName is one of thoses